# Function to search for specific number and then to further search for the suffix

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a huge amount of data to process in which 4 points with a related prefix needs to be subtracted from each other.

Example on the picture attached.
(let's call prefix a "ring number" and suffix time on the clock)
X value = any numerical value for each ID assigned

What I'm hoping to do is to search for the first number before the dot i.e. 300 and then subtract the value of 300.06-300.12 in one cell and in another cell 300.03-300.09.

(The subtraction is just an example, how I need to manipulate with the numbers is slightly more complicated, but I got this one under control)

This is my actual [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ4e2.jpg) and what I need to produce. right now, I'm doing it manually for each set of "rings".

Anyone knows how to approach this? I'm thinking vlookup, but I'm not very proficient in excel.

I tried vlookup, but I don't know how to construct the formula and I run out of ideas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, I have tried to simply the solution using Helper Columns but they may not be required at all. The formula gets too complex.

Also my suggestion is to replicate the ID in all blanks so that it gets a bit easier on formula.

See the below screenshot.

290 is repeated below again. This is not in your original sheet.

[image]

I2

```
=G2+VALUE(MID(H2,SEARCH("|",H2)+1,SEARCH(",",H2)-SEARCH("|",H2)-1))/100
```

J2

```
=G2+VALUE(MID(H2,SEARCH(",",H2)+1,SEARCH(")",H2)-SEARCH(",",H2)-2))/100
```

I3

```
=G3+VALUE(MID(H3,SEARCH("|",H3)+1,SEARCH(",",H3)-SEARCH("|",H3)-1))/100
```

J3

```
=G3+VALUE(MID(H3,SEARCH(",",H3)+1,SEARCH(")",H3)-SEARCH(",",H3)-2))/100
```

K2

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(J2,A:A,0))-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(I2,A:A,0))
```

K3

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(J3,A:A,0))-INDEX(B:B,MATCH(I3,A:A,0))
```

Similarly for Columns L & M just change the actual columns to C:C & D:D respectively.

All subtractions are available. Now construct your formula on these i.e. values in K, L & M

**Note - This solution will fail if you have a 3 digit number to append after decimal.** A different approach would be needed in that case.
So consider this answer as a draft/tentative one.